# Simplifying absolute value expression with square roots

Tags: inequality

I'm attempting to simplify the expression $|(|\sqrt2+ \sqrt3|-|\sqrt5-\sqrt7|)|$

Previously I've shown that if $0<a<b$ then $\sqrt{a}<\sqrt{b}$

Thus we have $\sqrt5-\sqrt7<0$ and therefore $|\sqrt5-\sqrt7|=\sqrt7-\sqrt5$

This means $|\sqrt2+\sqrt3|-|\sqrt5-\sqrt7|=\sqrt2+\sqrt3+\sqrt5-\sqrt7$

Now I've clearly simplified the expression, but I want to find out if it is possible to simplify further. As stated about $\sqrt5-\sqrt7<0$, and $\sqrt2+\sqrt3>0$. Intuitively I somehow see that this whole expression has to be greater than zero, but how do I prove it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be asking two questions: (1) can this be simplified further, and (2) is the expression positive or negative?

1. No.  There isn't really anything that you can do to make this expression simpler.  Each radical expression has a different radicand, so there are no like terms to combine, and the radicals themselves are pretty simple.
2. One possible approach, among many, is as follows:
   \begin{align}
   \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5} - \sqrt{7} \ge 0
        &\iff \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5} \ge \sqrt{7} \\
        &\iff \left( \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5} \right)^2 \ge 7. && (\text{$x \mapsto x^2$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$})
   \end{align}
   Multiplying out the expression on the left, we get
   \begin{align}
   \left(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}\right)^2
        &= 2 + \sqrt{6} + \sqrt{10} + \sqrt{6} + 3 + \sqrt{15} + \sqrt{10} + \sqrt{15} + 5 \\
        &= 10 + 2\sqrt{6} + 2\sqrt{10} + 2\sqrt{15}.
   \end{align}
   Therefore we have
   $$ \left( \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5} \right)^2 = 10 + \underbrace{2\sqrt{6} + 2\sqrt{10} + 2\sqrt{15}}_{\ge 0} \ge 10 > 7, $$
   from which it follows that
   $$ \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5} - \sqrt{7} > 0. $$

Comment: Yes you're right, I'm asking whether the expression is positive or negative, so that I know what to do with the absolute value signs. I really like your approach to this problem. First you see what it means that the expressions is greater than or equal to zero, and then you go about proving it. Thanks for your excellent input.

Answer (score 1):

When $a > 0, b > 0$, it is easy to see that $\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} > \sqrt{a + b}$. Thus we have $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{5} - \sqrt{7} > 0$. So you can prove something stronger - $$\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5} - \sqrt{7} > \sqrt{3} + 0 = \sqrt{3}.$$

Comment: This is a great answer (I upvoted), though I am always suspicious when someone says that something is "easy" (one person's "easy" is another's "impossible").  For completeness: $$ \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} > \sqrt{a+b} \iff (\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b})^2 > a+b.$$ But on the left, we have $a + 2\sqrt{ab} + b$, and $2\sqrt{ab} > 0$, from which the desired result follows.

Comment: I totally agree with Xander. For me this inequality is not so obvious when looking at the general case, but we could for example consider the fact that $\sqrt4+\sqrt4=2+2=4$ and $\sqrt8=\sqrt{4+4}<\sqrt9=3$ and $3<4.$

Comment: @Xander, Afflon, I agree that it is not obvious. I myself did what Xander did, i.e. square and then noting that $2\sqrt{ab} > 0$. Thanks, my bad!

Answer (score 0):

we have $$\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}>0$$ and since $$|a-b|=|b-a|$$ our term is $$\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{7}$$ and we have
$$\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}>\sqrt{7}$$
all Terms are positive and we get by squaring
$$2(\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{15}+\sqrt{10})>-3$$ which is true.